# Python requests from HTML are returning blanks?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-firefoxdriver, python-requests-html

New to programming and trying to learn Python using ATBS and the web. I am running into the issue when I send requests, I get blanks in return? I asked Reddit and even download the file as a .txt file in which I found two mentions of the number I was trying to find. But the CSS path selector that I am obtaining is outputting []? I am finding other mention of the number via HTML but not the section of the html I am after.

Questions:

1. Am I meant to copy using the CCS selector or CSS path?

Code source and website html images:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABIq0.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I109.png

Thanks.

Here is the website from which I am trying to get the stock price number from: https://www.nzx.com/instruments/WBC
also tried getting it from google, but had not luck: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=westpac+nz+share+price&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYyxCN7k8VlOKPGk8EhszcUZWbOuzsBM4&ved=0ahUKEwjNkKj2k6j6AhWNDt4KHUPcD8sQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=westpac+nz+share+price&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: Please ask one question.  Please post your code (as simple as possible), otherwise it's imposible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firefox copy CSS selector not CSS path. As mentioned in the video, I just happened to overlook it. Using CSS selector I was able to get the answer I was after.